# How did the Ghost locate Luis and his friends' workplace?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* Ava the Ghost suddenly appeared in Luis' workplace when Sonny Burch and his fellows were interrogating him.

How did she find the workplace?

Was she chasing Burch and his companions?

If she was inside the building all the time (assuming she was chasing them), why didn't she interfere from the first second?

Or was it just a coincidence? For example, Ava was walking outside the building and accidentally heard someone is talking about Scott Lang inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The building they are in is the X-Con Security Consultants Office or the business owned by Scott and Luis, seems like a sensible place to go to try and find Scott and the mobile laboratory. As for how she found the workplace? Well it wouldn't be a very good office if no customers could find it.